# What is the Purpose of argument in pthread_exit?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, pthread-join

basically, I am trying to understand the real purpose of pthread_exit.
  As you can see, there are multiple pthread_exit code I have tried. 
    And Following are the result i observe :

```
- Exit 1: 42
- Exit 2: 42
- Exit 3: thread failed
- Exit 4: error
- Exit 5: 42
- Without a pthread_exit statement: 42
```

Anyways the value passed(10) to pthread_exit is ignored(Exit 2) and prints the value which we modified via the pointer(42). 
So what is the real purpose of argument of pthread_exit here? confusing.

```
int a;
void *myThread(void *result)
{
       int a = 5;
        *((int*)result) = 42;
        pthread_exit(result);      // Exit 1
      //pthread_exit((void *)10);  // Exit 2
      //pthread_exit(0);           // Exit 3
      //pthread_exit();            // Exit 4
      //pthread_exit((void *)&a);  // Exit 5
}
int main()
{
   pthread_t tid;
   void *status = 0;
   int result;

   pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThread, &result);
   pthread_join(tid, &status);

   if (status != 0 ) {
       printf("%d\n",result);
   } else {
       printf("thread failed\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pthread_exit()` takes the pointer value you pass it and arranges for the pointer value to be returned into the `void *` variable whose address is passed to `pthread_join()`.

In your case, this means that the value passed to `pthread_exit()` will end up in the `status` variable in `main()`.  You never print the contents of `status` - all you do is test it against `NULL` in the `if ()` condition.  The value you are printing is the value stored in `result`, which is not modified by the `pthread_exit()` or `pthread_join()`, so of course it will always be the same.

In your `my_thread()` function, the pointer `result` is always going to be the address of the `result` variable in `main()`, so these are the cases you will see:

```
pthread_exit(result);      // Exit 1
```

In `main()`, `status` will end up equal to `(void *)&result`, which is necessarily non-NULL, so the test succeeds.  It then prints the value of `result`, which was set to `42` by the first line of `my_thread()`.

```
pthread_exit((void *)10);  // Exit 2
```

In `main()`, `status` will end up equal to `(void *)10`.  On any common implementation of C, this value will compare unequal to `NULL`, so the test succeeds.  It then prints the value of `result`, which was set to `42` by the first line of `my_thread()`.

```
pthread_exit(0);           // Exit 3
```

In `main()`, `status` will end up equal to `(void *)0`.  This necessarily compares equal to `NULL`, so the test fails.  It then prints "thread failed".

If you print the value of the `status` pointer with:

```
printf("status = %p\n", status);
```

before the `if()`, you will be able to see how the value passed to `pthread_exit()` is returned.